# Can maxItems/minItems be used with a $ref in a JSON schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

Given a JSON schema with the following in the definitions section:

```
"phoneNumber": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "countryCode": {
                    "type": "number"
                    },
                "areaCode": {
                    "type": "number"
                    },
                "number": {
                    "type": "number"
                    },
                "extension": {
                    "type": "number"
                    },
                "service": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": ["Voice", "Fax", "Data"]
                    },
                "class": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": ["Switchboard", "Direct", "PA", "Mobile"]
                    }
                }
            }
```

If I want to include phoneNumber elsewhere using a $ref and want the JSON to validate if it contains multiple occurrences of phoneNumber, can I use maxItems/minItems:

```
"person": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
            },
        "phoneNumber": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/phoneNumber"
            //can I use maxItems/minItems here?
            }
        }
    }
```

Can I use maxItems and minItems here, or would I have to do something like this below for it to validate:

```
"phoneNumber": {
    "allOf": { "$ref": "#/definitions/phoneNumber" },
    "maxItems": 4
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$ref` must stand alone.  The option you identified using `allOf` is the best way to do it.

> Any members other than "$ref" in a JSON Reference object SHALL be ignored.
>
> - https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pbryan-zyp-json-ref-03#section-3